# Using list data in a Stash Embed

Tags: stash

I have a couple of formats that a news story can display on the site. I have each of these as a different Stash embed.

They're named in this format: `story-block`, `story-focal`, `story-standard`.

The site is in a magazine format and so uses many different styles on one page, often mix and matching them.

For example, on the homepage it loads in 16 blog posts, the first 4 are in `story-block` format, the next 6 are in `story-standard` format and the final is in `story-block` format.

The following code doesn't work, but demonstrates the concept I'm trying to achieve.

```
  <div class="two-by">
    {exp:stash:get_list name="news" limit="4"}
      {exp:stash:embed:modules:story-block process="start"}
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
  </div>

  {exp:stash:get_list name="news" limit="6" offset="4"}
    {exp:stash:embed:modules:story-standard}
  {/exp:stash:get_list}

  {exp:stash:get_list name="news" limit="1" offset="10"}
    {exp:stash:embed:modules:story-block}
  {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

`story-block` has the following markup:-

```
<article class="story story--block">
  <a href="{url}">
    <img src="{photo}">
    <div class="story__details">
      <h2 class="main-title">{title}</h2>
      {excerpt}
      <div class="mini-meta">
        <span>{type}</span>
        <span>{date}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</article>
```

But when rendered it doesn't load in the data, it will still show `{title}`.

My inkling is that embedding with `process="start"` should do the trick as it would then work as an EE snippet would, but this doesn't make a difference.

If I don't embed and instead copy the code directly into the template it works fine - but this is going to lead to massive code duplication around the site.

Is this possible, or is there a workaround?

Comment: If I pass the listed values into the embed (ie `{exp:stash:embed name="modules:story-block" stash:title="{title}"}` it works, but I feel like that is an unnecessary step and there is probably a parameter to share the same vars as where it was called from (as a snippet would vs this embed-like method)

Comment: Try changing your stash embed code from {exp:stash:embed:.... to {stash:embed:... (remove the "exp"}?

Comment: That did it, thanks Romans. Submit it as an answer and I'll approve it :-)

Comment: Why use a stash embed here at all?  A snippet would work fine.

Comment: Snippets would be loaded on each page. They're loaded early, and even snippets you don't need are loaded on page load. With Stash embeds you can make them work as if they're snippets without that overhead. But on this particular site I think you're right, snippets would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the stash embed from 
`{exp:stash:embed:....` to `{stash:embed:...` (remove the "exp").